# Program done but not running correctly

Tags: python, python-3.x

The point of this program is to match an authors signature (style of writing ) to their pieces in order to figure out who the author is. I'm basically done with the program, but when I go to run it, other than the first prompt where it asks for the name of the file, it does nothing. I can't figure out why it's not moving on with the file. It gives me a "That file is not found" print message but the file IS in the right directory so I don't know what's going on.

Pretty big program relatively speaking, so I don't expect people to really get in depth, but I just cant figure it out by myself.

```
import os.path, math

def clean_up(s):
    ''' Return a version of string str in which all letters have been
    converted to lowercase and punctuation characters have been stripped 
    from both ends. Inner punctuation is left untouched. '''

    punctuation = '''!"',;:.-?)([]<>*#\n\t\r'''
    result = s.lower().strip(punctuation)
    return result


def average_word_length(text):
    ''' Return the average length of all words in text. Do not
    include surrounding punctuation in words. 
    text is a non-empty list of strings each ending in \n.
    At least one line in text contains a word.'''

    words = text.split()
    for word in words:
            average=sum(len(word) for word in words)/len(words)        
    return average


def type_token_ratio(text):
    ''' Return the type token ratio (TTR) for this text.
    TTR is the number of different words divided by the total number of words.
    text is a non-empty list of strings each ending in \n.
    At least one line in text contains a word. '''
    uniquewords=dict()
    words=0
    for line in text.splitlines():
        line=line.strip().split()
        for word in line:
            words+=1
            if word in uniquewords:
                uniquewords[word]+=1
            else:
                uniquewords[word]=1
    TTR= len(uniquewords)/words
    return TTR


def hapax_legomana_ratio(text):
    ''' Return the hapax_legomana ratio for this text.
    This ratio is the number of words that occur exactly once divided
    by the total number of words.
    text is a list of strings each ending in \n.
    At least one line in text contains a word.'''

    uniquewords = dict()
    words = 0
    for line in text.splitlines():
        line = line.strip().split()
        for word in line:
            words += 1
            word = word.replace(',', '').strip()
            if word in uniquewords:
                uniquewords[word] -= 1
            else:
                uniquewords[word] = 1

    unique_count = 0
    for each in uniquewords:
        if uniquewords[each] == 1:
            unique_count += 1
    HLR = unique_count/words

    return HLR    


def split_on_separators(original, separators):
    ''' Return a list of non-empty, non-blank strings from the original string
    determined by splitting the string on any of the separators.
    separators is a string of single-character separators.'''


    result = []
    newstring=''

    for char in original:
        if char in separators:
            result.append(newstring)
            newstring=''
            if '' in result:
                result.remove('')
        else:
            newstring+=char
    return result

def average_sentence_length(text):
    ''' Return the average number of words per sentence in text.
    text is guaranteed to have at least one sentence.
    Terminating punctuation defined as !?.
    A sentence is defined as a non-empty string of non-terminating
    punctuation surrounded by terminating punctuation
    or beginning or end of file. '''
    words=0
    Sentences=0
    for line in text.split():
        words+=1
    sentence=split_on_separators(text,'?!.')
    for sep in sentence:
        Sentences+=1

    ASL=words/Sentences
    return ASL


def avg_sentence_complexity(text):
    '''Return the average number of phrases per sentence.
    Terminating punctuation defined as !?.
    A sentence is defined as a non-empty string of non-terminating
    punctuation surrounded by terminating punctuation
    or beginning or end of file.
    Phrases are substrings of a sentences separated by
    one or more of the following delimiters ,;: '''
    Sentences=0
    Phrases=0
    sentence=split_on_separators(text,'?!.')
    for sep in sentence:
        Sentences+=1
    Phrase=split_on_separators(text, ',;:')
    for n in Phrase:
        Phrases+=1
    ASC=Phrases/Sentences
    return ASC


def get_valid_filename(prompt):
    '''Use prompt (a string) to ask the user to type the name of a file. If
    the file does not exist, keep asking until they give a valid filename.
    Return the name of that file.'''


    filename = input(prompt)
    if os.path.isfile(filename) == False:
        print ("That file does not exist.")
        filename = input(prompt)

    return filename


def read_directory_name(prompt):
    '''Use prompt (a string) to ask the user to type the name of a directory. If
    the directory does not exist, keep asking until they give a valid directory.
    '''

    dirname = input(prompt)
    if os.path.isfile(dirname)== False:
        print ("That directory does not exist.")
        dirname=input(prompt)
    return dirname


def compare_signatures(sig1, sig2, weight):
    '''Return a non-negative real number indicating the similarity of two 
    linguistic signatures. The smaller the number the more similar the 
    signatures. Zero indicates identical signatures.
    sig1 and sig2 are 6 element lists with the following elements
    0  : author name (a string)
    1  : average word length (float)
    2  : TTR (float)
    3  : Hapax Legomana Ratio (float)
    4  : average sentence length (float)
    5  : average sentence complexity (float)
    weight is a list of multiplicative weights to apply to each
    linguistic feature. weight[0] is ignored.
    '''

    i=1
    while i <=5:
        result +=(abs(sig1[i]-sig2[i]))*weight[i]
        i+=1
    return  result


def read_signature(filename):
    '''Read a linguistic signature from filename and return it as 
    list of features. '''

    file = open(filename, 'r')
    # the first feature is a string so it doesn't need casting to float
    result = [file.readline()]
    # all remaining features are real numbers
    for line in file:
        result.append(float(line.strip()))
    return result


if __name__ == '__main__':

    prompt = 'enter the name of the file with unknown author:'
    mystery_filename = get_valid_filename(prompt)

    # readlines gives us the file as a list of strings each ending in '\n'
    text = open(mystery_filename, 'r').read()
    text.close()
    # calculate the signature for the mystery file
    mystery_signature = [mystery_filename]
    mystery_signature.append(average_word_length(text))
    mystery_signature.append(type_token_ratio(text))
    mystery_signature.append(hapax_legomana_ratio(text))
    mystery_signature.append(average_sentence_length(text))
    mystery_signature.append(avg_sentence_complexity(text))

    weights = [0, 11, 33, 50, 0.4, 4]

    prompt = 'enter the path to the directory of signature files: '
    dir = read_directory_name(prompt)
    # every file in this directory must be a linguistic signature
    files=os.listdir(dir)

    # to do: Get list of all files in directory name we just got. 
    # store it in a list called 'files'

    # we will assume that there is at least one signature in that directory
    this_file = files[0]
    signature = read_signature('{} {}'.format(dir,this_file))
    best_score = compare_signatures(mystery_signature, signature, weights)
    best_author = signature[0]
    for this_file in files[1:]:
        signature = read_signature('{} {}'.format(dir,this_file))
        score = compare_signatures(mystery_signature, signature, weights)
        if score < best_score:
            best_score = score
            best_author = signature[0]
    print( "best author match: {} with score {}".format(best_author, best_score))
```

Answer (score 1):

In the following line (appear twice), path is generate by joining dir part and filename part with **space**.

```
signature = read_signature('{} {}'.format(dir,this_file))
#                             ^
```

You should use [`os.sep`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.sep) to join them.

```
signature = read_signature('{}{}{}'.format(dir, os.sep, this_file))
```

or more preferably, use [`os.path.join`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.join):

```
signature = read_signature(os.path.join(dir, this_file))
```

Comment: The error without the exception is a FileNotFoundError but I'm working in the right directory so I don't get why it doesn't open.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it reports "That file does not exist." rather than "That directory does not exist."?

In `read_directory_name(prompt)` the author uses `os.path.isfile(path)` and the docs for it are "Return True if path is an existing regular file. (...)".

Since you are looking for a directory you need `os.path.isdir` or `os.path.exists`.